# How to call model function inside root folder of CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am facing problem to call model from the root directory of CI folder.
I have made apis in apis folder of ci but not inside of application folder.
My all ci controller and model are reside in application folder like
`MY_PROJECT/application/controllers/Controllers_files.ext`
`MY_PROJECT/application/models/Models_files.ext`

but My apis are reside in `MY_PROJECT/apis/apisfile.ext`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$apppath =  str_replace('apis', '', dirname(__FILE__));


include($apppath.'system/core/Model.php'); # if you didnt call this, it will throw  
# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Ab\My\E-Tech\application\models\product_model.php on line 3
require($apppath.'application/models/Notification_model.php'); # Model Name



$object  = new Notification_model();
$object->sendNotification($title='dharmendra', $message="chaudhary", $row_data, $type=1, $type_id=1);
```

Comment: You can move MY_PROJECT/apis/apisfile.ext to MY_PROJECT/application/controller/apis/apisfile.ext and then create an object as $CI = &get_instance(); you can use $CI->load->model('Yourmodel'); as you would normally do.

Comment: I cannot do that because all permission module reside inside the application folder likes auth component

Comment: Is that creating a problem? do you think its a security risk to move apis inside application folder?

Comment: ya security issues . also if i paste the folder inside the controller folder than how i call the apis from url

Comment: Do  one thing try load your api  on your perticular controller method .But folder will be at assets/api/ only.